# Virtual Environment's Activate Does Nothing

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

So, I switched to my new laptop and tried to install VirtualEnv on the latest version of Python. Even though it is successfully installed, when I create a new virtual environment and try to activate it, it switches to a new line as nothing has happened. I checked the folder, I'm entering the right path, it's not in "bin" folder. I'm not sure what's causing the problem. I have to note that I'm on Windows and I'm not using PowerShell. any ideas?

P.S. Please note that I know that it must show the VirtualEnv's name in parenthesis but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: what command are you typing to activate the environment? please add the full command

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz LoginSysEnv\Scripts\activate . This worked on my previous system.

Comment: have you tried using `activate.bat` ?

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz yes I did but still, nothing!

Comment: have you tried closing the console/restarting windows?

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz Yeah. It turned out it works on Powershell only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue earlier today. What solved it for me was running the \scripts\activate.ps1 command in Powershell as Admin

Comment: This works but I was just wondering, why Command Prompt can't handle that?

Comment: Im not sure, I think it might have something to do with how command prompt is run where as powershell is more a terminal I think

Comment: @Blademaster680 I think this problem is related with the difference between command prompt and powerShell. I had the similar problem and just noticed that I was using powerShell instead of command prompt. After switching back to command prompt, problem solved and everything is working under expectation.

Answer (score 4):

1)Run Powershell as Administrator

2) Run the following command in powershell: Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

3) Rerun the activation command: > venv\Scripts\activate.ps1